# Why increasing number of threads is useless?

Tags: java, multithreading, rabbitmq

I've been looking for the way to increase the speed of processing messages received from rabbitmq queue. The only way I've found is make more than one threads doing the same - receiving and processing. And this gave me some profit. After I created 4 threads the speed quadrupled. As I have 8-core processor I've decided to increase the number of threads to 8. But this gives no performance increasing. YourKit shows that only 50% of CPU is used. Somebody can say that my app is lightweight and so it is so, but I can say that it can't do more work than it does regardless I produce much more what to do. Why this doesn't work?

Comment: Are there still topics on the queue when you reach 50% of CPU load? Perhaps you don't send enough topics to the queue or the bottleneck i now somewhere else.

Comment: You probably have a serialization part in your algorithm which renders fruitless the increase in the number of threads.

Comment: You say you have an 8-core CPU. Are you sure that's really true? Or is it really a 4-core CPU with hyper-threading? Those look like 8-core CPUs to a lot of tools, but hyper-threading doesn't actually give you those extra cores, just faster context-switches.

Comment: What are you doing when you receive the messages? How many messages are backed up in the queue? **Are you using transactional messages (that would greatly slow down performance)?**

Comment: [check this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/616109/Java-Thread-Tutorial#sem) :D, running to much threads with CPU is just like disaster, especially if threads synchronize with each other

Answer (score 4):

There are many different issues that can constrain the maximum speed of some application on a given system. For example, it can be limited by memory bandwidth, by [Amdahl's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law) effects (time needed for non-parallel code, including synchronized blocks), I/O bandwidth, and cache space.

If you want further improvement you need to do some measurements and profiling to find where the time is going, and then work on that.

Answer (score 3):

The short (and not particularly helpful) answer is "overheads and bottlenecks".

For instance:

- Creating threads in Java is relatively expensive.  If the amount of work done by a thread isn't large, the overhead of creating the thread can out-weigh the benefits.
- Context switching between threads is relatively expensive, especially when you take account of memory-related overheads such as cache misses, TLB misses.  (These overheads actually hit when a native thread is assigned to a core.  If the OS can somehow keep a native thread on a single core continuously (i.e. with no other threads on the same core), then it can use spinlocking ... and avoid the context switch.  But the more Java threads you have, the less likely it is that the OS can do this.)
- The threads may be spending a large proportion of their time waiting for I/O to complete.  The I/O system's throughput or the speed / latency of some external service can be a bottleneck.
- You may have contention over data structures; e.g. threads requiring exclusive access to safely read or update (say) a shared Map.  If threads regularly need to wait for others to release locks, then you have a bottleneck.
- Your computation may be dominated by the costs of "feeding" the threads.  For example, if there is a single master thread that hands out "work" to worker threads, then the master thread's activities could be the bottleneck; i.e. it may not be able to provide enough work to keep the workers busy.

---

Since your tags imply that you are using a message queue, it is possible that that is the bottleneck, especially if the messages are big or the "work" done on each one is relatively small.

(Using a separate separate message queue service is liable to increase context switches, add I/O latency, add protocol overheads and so on.  It's not an automatic route to performance improvement for small-scale systems.)

---

It is also possible that you have "hyperthreaded" cores not real cores, or that the operating system is stopping your JVM from using all cores.

Answer (score 1):

If CPU or waiting for IO is your bottle neck, adding independent threads can make a big difference.

If you have a shared resource is a bottleneck, e.g. your L3 cache, your network adapter, your kernel, adding threads won't help because CPU is not the problem.  In fact it can often make it worse by adding overhead.

> my app is lightweight

In which case CPU is unlikely to be your issue and you are doing well to see a speed up with more than 1 CPU.  Most likely you are speeding up CPU used by RabbitMQ.  Ideally it should be more efficient and this shouldn't really help much.  IMHO, more efficient messaging solutions don't gain much by multiple CPUs as they will not be bottlenecked on CPU.

Comment: It's difficult for me to find the meaning in your answer for me. I'm shure that the CPU is the bottleneck. When I had only one consuming thread YourKit've been showing that only 13-16% of the CPU was used. After I've increased it to 4 threads this value changed to 40-50%. Producer can produce more messages, but as the consumer don't send acks fast enoug it can't send more. I'm shure that the rabbitmq server can send up to 2000 mesgs/s. making allowances for the size of my msgs I'm agree to receive 1000 or even 800 but not 400-450

Comment: @NikitinMikhail Free CPU doesn't indicate that adding more CPU will help.  It only indicates you can add more threads.  If the bottleneck is the L3 cache, or the amount of garbage you are producing the CPU usage will max out on each thread but you don't get any more throughput (but you often get higher latencies)  While RabbitMQ might do 2000 msg/second, this usually doesn't include anything else like writing or reading those messages, they usually test/quote untouched byte[].

Answer (score 1):

One way or another, you're only using 4 cores.  There's a lot that can stop stop you from doubling your performance by doubling your threads, but from your 4 thread success you've gotten past all that.  I'm guessing there's a bug in your code to set off 8 threads and it's only firing up 4.  (Even with hyperthreading, you're going to get *some* improvement.  Even with every possible problem, you're going to get *some* improvement.)  Otherwise, I'll go with T.J.Crowder and Stephen C:  I don't think you really have 8 cores.

I'd try using different numbers of threads: 3, 5, 6.  See what changes.  I think you'll stumble on the problem soon enough.

To be fair to Java:  if you write thread-safe code and avoid bottlenecks, it handles threads really well, as you've noticed going from one thread to 4.  I've always found the overhead costs to be trivial.

Comment: You know,when I'm looking to the profiler I see that only 50% of the CPU is used(wheather 4 threads or 8). Doesn't the number of core following from this?

Comment: @NikitinMikhail:  Probably. You seem to be hitting a brick wall, while typical thread-performance problems are more dramatic--only one thread runs at a time--or less dramatic--for instance, your 8 threads giving you only 60-80% CPU instead of 100. I see only two answers. Either you've got a bug in your code and are only running 4 threads instead of 8 or you've only got 4 working cores. (Even lousy hyperthreading should get you above 50%.) If three threads use less CPU but 5 & 6 do nothing, it's the cores. If you realize you were using 4 when you thought you were using 8, then it's a bug.

Comment: @NikitinMikhail: The key thing is that brick wall.  Looking over the other answers, while they explain slow-downs, they down't explain _that_.

Answer (score 0):

Your application does not have linear speedup, and therefore, it does not have good scalability.

In order to keep increase the number of threads you need to ensure the data being handle is growing accordingly.  For a fixed amount of data, increasing number of threads (and/or cores) will have a diminishing return at some point since the overhead of creating threads will outweight the thread's compute time.

Make sure to look up the following link:

- [Ahmdahl's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law)
- [Gustafson's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gustafson%27s_law)

Gustafson's law is a great counterpoint to Ahmdal's law so I highly recommend understanding that article.