# Turn on Parallel Processing in DBSCAN

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, parallel-processing

I'm trying to use multiple cores with sklearn's [DBSCAN](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html), but the run time doesn't seem to change when I change `n_jobs = -1` (use all processors to run parallel jobs as the documentation suggests). What am I missing?

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import euclidean_distances
from time import time
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN

# generate a symmetric distance matrix
num_training_examples = 10000
num_features = 10
X = np.random.randint(5, size=(num_training_examples, num_features))
D = euclidean_distances(X,X)

# DBSCAN parameters
eps = 0.25
kmedian_thresh = 0.005
min_samples = 5

# case 1: omit n_jobs arg from DBSCAN
start = time()
db = DBSCAN(eps=eps,
            min_samples = min_samples,
            metric='precomputed').fit(D)
end = time()
total_time = end - start
print('DBSCAN took {} seconds for {} training examples without n_jobs arg'\
       .format(total_time,num_training_examples))


# case 2: add n_jobs arg to DBSCAN
n_jobs = -1
start = time()
db = DBSCAN(eps=eps,
            min_samples = min_samples,
            metric='precomputed',
            n_jobs=n_jobs).fit(D)
end = time()
total_time = end - start
print('DBSCAN took {} seconds for {} training examples with n_jobs arg'\
       .format(total_time,num_training_examples,n_jobs))
```

- `DBSCAN took 0.710000038147 seconds for 10000 training examples without n_jobs arg`
- `DBSCAN took 0.707999944687 seconds for 10000 training examples with n_jobs = -1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Not overhead problems. Op already has the answer in the comments, [n_jobs is not used if the metric is precomputed.](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/16299)

<s>In short, you are having overhead problems.</s>

You are training with only 10000, so the optimal number of jobs needed may not be a lot. Think it the hard way, if you have 100 registers and create a job for each register, the time needed to create a job can be bigger than the time to treat a register, right? Yes, I know it's a really extreme case, but in a small scale is what may happen to you.

If you want to do an empirical analysis, you can try to increase the jobs one by one and calculate the time, and then also start increasing the number of registers. You will notice the difference.

There are a lot of explanations in stack overflow, [here you have one about threads.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17550139/why-increasing-number-of-threads-is-useless)

Comment: @random_dsp_guy, wow, did not know that. I edit the answer then.